# ConTeXt: Number and caption for subfigures (combination)

Tags: captions, context

The ConTeXt way of creating subfigures is using a `combination`. They seem to support either captions or numbering, but not both.

Let's consider the following example:

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\setupcombinations[alternative=text]

\starttext
\startplacefigure[title=Test]
    \startcombination[2*2]
        \startcontent\externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]\stopcontent
        \startcaption Test\stopcaption
        \startcontent\externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]\stopcontent
        \startcaption Test\stopcaption
        \startcontent\externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]\stopcontent
        \startcaption Test\stopcaption
        \startcontent\externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]\stopcontent
        \startcaption Test\stopcaption
    \stopcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```

This results in non-numbered captions for the "subfigures"

[image: caption not numbered]

Using `alternative=label` destroys the whole `combination` as it treats every caption as own image but attaches labels (a, b, c etc.) to every image.

My aim is to reproduce something like the `subcaption`  package does in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\subcaption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: subcaptions]

As you can see, the subfigures are images that are automatically labeled/numbered.

*Question:* How to have captions in a `combination` in ConTeXt that are automatically numbered?

Comment: `alternative=text` treats every second item as a caption, while `alternative=label` adds a label to each item, so it looks like you can't have both. Maybe you could use `inbetween` (in `\setupcombinations`) to insert labels automatically...

Comment: @DG' Well yes, it looks that way (that's the reason I asked here). Since LaTeX has many packages supporting something like that I assumed ConTeXt had a mechanism for it. Using `inbetween` unfortunately doesn't work as it does not insert the text on the level of the caption but in between…

Comment: Too bad. It would perhaps be best to ask the mailing list then

Comment: Did you mean `floatcombination`? [MWE](http://dpaste.com/39DE5KC), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNxFk.png).

Comment: @HenriMenke Please see my edit. With your example, I guess I would have to create an own float type for subfigures with a counter that resets at every figure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (imo) not very ConTeXy version to achieve subfigure numbering based on a suggestion by [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke) (see [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500815/context-number-and-caption-for-subfigures-combination#comment1265116_500815)).

[image: subfigure in ConTeXt]

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\setupcombinations[alternative=text]

\definefloat[subfigure][local=yes]
\setupcaption[subfigure][numberconversion=a]
\setuplabeltext[subfigure=]

\appendvalue{stopplacefigure}{\resetcounter[subfigure]}

\starttext
\startplacefigure[title=Test]
    \startfloatcombination[2*2]
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
    \stopfloatcombination
\stopplacefigure
\startplacefigure[title=Test]
    \startfloatcombination[2*2]
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
      \startplacesubfigure[title=Test]
        \externalfigure[dummy][width=4cm,height=1cm]
      \stopplacesubfigure
    \stopfloatcombination
\stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```